# How to remove the text "entries" on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, datatables

Datatables contains "Show [dropdown] entries", for choosing how many rows the table should display at a time.

I know how to remove "Show [dropdown] entries" all together by removing the `l` from this.

```
dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-6"l><"col-sm-6"f>>tp',
```

How do I remove the part "*entries*" of "Show [dropdown] entries"?

**DOM added:**

```
<div id="tableComputerPackages_length" class="dataTables_length">
    <label>
        Show
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="tableComputerPackages_length" aria-controls="tableComputerPackages">
        entries
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply change the language `sLengthMenu` setting from `"Show _MENU_ entries"` to

```js
var table = $("#example").dataTable({
    language : {
        sLengthMenu: "Show _MENU_"
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wj32k7ck/**

Comment: I have this allready, "                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], ["10", "25", "50", "100", "All"]],
"
How would you change that?

Comment: Im using a newer version of datatable where you don't prefix with 's'.

Comment: I have added my DOM if it helps.

Comment: @radbyx, datatables is backwards compatible regarding naming, in fact the fiddle demo above is in datatables **1.10.6**!! (most recent version); what do you mean by "_lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], ["10", "25", "50", "100", "All"]]_", do you want to change the content of the dropdown too? language.sLengthmenu !== lenghmenu

Comment: I mean this is how I implement the property "lengthMenu" already. I just wanted you to see it, because you're suggestion will override my existing code and I have to keep my array to show the options in the dropdown. :)

Comment: @radbyx, you are confusing [lengthMenu](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) with [language.lengthMenu / language.sLengthMenu](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html)

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I works now. I'm so grateful :-)

Comment: It works with                     "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_"
too. "lengthMenu" reads a little better than "sLengthMenu" i think.

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for accepting the answer. Yes, lengthMenu is more plain and readable, but sLengthMenu makes better distinguish.

Answer (score 4):

On Datatables 1.10 and up it's:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_"
  }
});
```

[Here's the full documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.info).

As a bonus, if you want to tweak the length menu wording (i.e. *show x entries*) you do that like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records"
  }
});
```

and [here's the documentation for that](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.lengthMenu).